# How to create onBeforeLoad as a command?

Tags: typescript, selenium, cypress

I have created a script that is navigating to a URL with a onBeforeLoad using Cypress:

```
const bomMessage = cy.stub().as('bom');
cy.visit('https://helloworld.com', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    win.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.event === 'ReadyToGo') {
        bomMessage(event.data);
      }
    });
  },
});
```

But here is my problem, I have a scenario where I enter a url e.g. helloworld.com and inside the link there is a button called "Take me to next page" - when i'm clicking on that button, then I want the onBeforeLoad to be triggered. My idea was to perhaps be able to make the

```
onBeforeLoad(win) {
    win.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.event === 'ReadyToGo') {
        bomMessage(event.data);
      }
    });
  },
```

as a command which I can call whenever I want in my script that waits for it to happen else fails.

Is it possible to make the addEventListener to be called whenever I want in my test instead of having it inside the cy.visit call?

EDITED after answer:

```
Given('works', () => {
  const bomMessage = cy.stub().as('bom');

  cy.visit('https://helloworld.com')

  cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.event === 'ReadyToGo') {
        bomMessage(event.data);
      }
    });
  });

  cy.get('@bom').should('be.calledOnce');
});
```

Comment: Maybe EventFiringDecorator is what you are looking for?: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringDecorator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onBeforeLoad` hook is so that it's ready for `message` event that happens during the initial page visit.

But you can set it anywhere in the test before the trigger (in your case the button click).

You just need the `win` object.

```js
cy.visit(...)                  // no listener here

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    // set up the listener
  });
}

cy.get('my-button').click()  // triggers message event
```

Comment: Hello ! Appreciate for the help! It actually worked semi but I wonder if I could improve it some how? I have edited my thread to show you what I have done and wonder if I could perhaps remove the stub() in my case?

Comment: I don't think so. The stub records the call. You could instead have a variable and increment it inside the event listener, but problem is you'd have a mixture of async and sync code. IMO stub is best.